What is the equivalent of a normal closure in an inverse semigroup?
Quick question:

What is the terminology for the analogue of the normal closure of a set in a group, applied to an inverse semigroup?

I do believe such a notion exists; I have just forgotten the name for it and, naturally with these things, I can't find it anywhere, not even Lawson's, "Inverse Semigroups" - at least not anywhere obvious.
Clarification:

Definition: The normal closure of a subset $S$ of a group $G$ is defined as
$$\operatorname{ncl}_G(S)=\bigcap_{H\unlhd G,\\ S\subseteq H}H.$$

I'm looking for the name of
$$\bigcap_{N\unlhd I,\\ S\subseteq N}N$$
for $N$ a normal subsemigroup${}^\dagger$ and an inverse semigroup $I$.

I think it's also the normal closure but I'm writing slides for an important presentation, so I'm having doubts.
Or is it (also) the normal subsemigroup of $I$ generated by $S$?

$\dagger$: Lawson:

An inverse subsemigroup $N$ of an inverse semigroup $S$ is said to be self- conjugate if $s^{-1}Ns \subseteq N$ for all $s\in S$. A full, self-conjugate inverse sub-semigroup of $S$ is called a normal subsemigroup of $S$.


If you are not sure of an official term, and you can't find one, just say "by analogy with the construction in groups, let us call... the 'normal [subsemigroup] closure of S", and say during the presentation that you looked it up in Lawson but could not find standard terminology for it.
